# sails.sockets.broadcast RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: socket.io, sails.js

I have this code:

```
module.exports = {
    test: function(req, res) {
        Model.create({...}).exec(function (err, created) {
            if(err) { ... }

            sails.sockets.broadcast('abc', 'abc', created);

            return res.json({ ... });
        });
    }
};
```

And I get `RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded` thrown at `/node_modules/sails-mysql/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Parser.js:82`

When I remove the line `sails.sockets.broadcast(...)` it doesn't crash.

It wasn't really clear to me how I could find which line caused the error.  Even with the `node-debug` command.

Is this a bug in sails.js? How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Can we see the client code that listens for event 'abc'? You may be creating an infinite loop.